# How to make a Do-While loop with a MySQL connection to validate unique number using callbacks

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback, do-while

I have problems with a do/while statement.

I'm creating a unique number to identify the user in the users table (it's not the ID of the table) then I search in the table to see if that number is already taken with a do/while. If it's already taken then create a new one and also validate it, if it's not then continue.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'host',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'passwd',
  database: 'db'
});
var get_ID = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999) + 10000000;
}
function exist_ID(ID, callback) {
  var query = 'SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, "TRUE", "FALSE") AS RESULT FROM USERS WHERE USER_NUMBER = ' + ID + '';
  connection.query(query, function (error, results) {
    if (error) throw error;
    callback(results[0].RESULT);
  });
  connection.end();
}
var ID = get_ID();
exist_ID(ID, function (answer) {
  do {
    ID = get_ID();
    //?
  } while (answer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be really random?

If not, you could generate a number of a fixed length just like you did (all numbers will have 8 digits) and concatenate the ID (if it's and integer). You would have eight random digits followed by a unique integer.

Another solution could be to integrate a timestamp in it, `Date.now()` will give you the current timestamp as a number. (You can also convert it in hexadecimal to get shorter string, or up to Base36 - `Date.now().toString(36).length === 8`)

Note: **If you really want to make it work the way you started**, you can't handle async tasks in a do while, I would suggest that you use something similar to a recursive function.

It's not tested but here is a suggestion:

```
function generateRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999) + 10000000;
}

function getID(callback){
  var testID = generateRandomNumber();
  var query = buildQuery(testID); // returns 'SELECT...

  connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    // if true (count > 0) it exists, we call this function again
    if (results[0].RESULT) return getID(callback);

    // if we get here, it means that the ID doesn't exist in the DB
    connection.end();
    return callback(testID);
  });
}

var ID = null;
getId(uniqueID => {
  ID = uniqueID;
});
```

It's not really a recursive function, but the callback will only be called when a unique ID is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#doUntil) to simplify this task for yourself

```
doUntil(get_ID, exist_ID, function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
      ... handle errors
   }
   else {
      ... handle new user id
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use automatic sequencing for this, or if you must have random numbers try the insertion with whatever number you want and catch the duplicate key exception when and if it occurs. Any technique based on looking for it first is subject to timing window problems, and in any case is twice as inefficient.